# Customize the way stderr is appended to a file

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have an issue with a shell script that uses rsync to synchronize 2 directories. I'm storing the result of the rsync command (whether it's successful or not) to a file named status and in case there is a problem, the stderr output is appended to a file named error. However, I can't seem to find a way to enter a timestamp before the actual error in the error file.

In the end, I need something like this:

```
if rsync source destination 2>> error # but I need to have the date before the actual error is appended!
then
   echo "`date` - Success" >> status
else
   echo "`date` - Failure" >> status
fi
```

I've also tried the following:

```
(rsync source destination && echo "`date` - Success" >> status || echo "`date` - Failure" >> status) 2>>error
```

The only way I've made this work is when I store the stderr output to a temporary file, so that I can append its contents to the error file after I have entered the timestamp.

Comment: You have two different files: `status` and `error` and your two examples don't agree on what output goes where.  Can you describe exactly what you want to do?

Comment: On an unrelated note, assuming that you want stdout and stderr to go to the same place, you should remember that stdout is usually buffered whereas stderr is not, which means stderr will almost always arrive before stdout if both go to the same place.

Comment: You are right, I've just edited it! I'll try to explain what I want a bit clearer: the status file should contain only the date and a success or failure entry, while the error file should contain the date and the output of stderr (in case there is an error, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
rsync -av blah blah 2>&1|perl -e "while(<>){s/^/`date`  /g; print;}" >>logfile
```

It will add the date and some spaces to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Perfect! This does exactly what I want!

Comment: Hi again! Is there a way to insert an IF statement in there, in order to have the Success/Failure messages appended to another file (check my description)?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been more than 3 months since I asked this question, but I thought it would be nice to show what I ended up doing in my shell script.

As I've described, I needed to somehow catch stderr, in order to manipulate it in a log file, e.g. add a timestamp. I was able to do this using files and with what Patrick suggested, but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible.

So, this is how I worked it out:

```
if ! result=$(command_that_will_produce_errors 2>&1 1>/dev/null)
then
    echo "There was an error on $(date): $result" >> logfile
else
    echo "Command executed successfully on $(date)" >> logfile
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Greg's Wiki has an entry on [adding timestamps to every line of a stream](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/107) that covers several methods, depending on your environment. They all come down to piping the stream through a loop/process that adds in the timestamps; the POSIX-compliant version is:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S) $line"
done
```

Comment: also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Rather than just provide a link, please at least include a brief summary in your answer...

Comment: the links says everything that needs to be said, and that site is great for learning bash; you will click it.

Comment: Yes, it is a great reference. However, this site is a wiki, not a link farm. Downvoting. Happy to restore your point when you update your response...

Comment: I couldn't care less about the voting. I provide answers and sometimes the answer is just "read that"

Comment: @Samus_ We really do prefer if the answers are capable of standing alone, in case the link breaks or users have already seen it and decided it's not helpful (there are a number of meta.SO questions about this, particularly [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)). I edited yours this time; we typically just leave a comment and delete them

Comment: go ahead. that is my answer and if you don't like it then it's your lose.

Comment: also notice you misquoted the answer

Comment: This works fine, thank you very much Samus_! Also, thank you Michael Mrozek for the edit!